# How can I create a legend for confidence interval and line of best fit for a stat_smooth in a lm (ggplot2)

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

Hi I have a great regression graph with 95% confidence interval and best fit line, however cant seem to add a legend, I've tried aes, scale_colour_manual, in various locations but to no avail.
My code so far is

```
ggplot(bats, aes(x=Days, y=AI))+geom_point(size=2, alpha=0.5) +
  xlab("Number of survey days") +
  ylab("Bat Activity Index")+
  stat_smooth( method = "lm",  formula = y~x,
    size = 1, col = "red", level = 0.95, alpha=0.5)+
  theme_light() +
  ggtitle("Regression test between Bat Activity Index and number of survey days")
```

[image: graph so far]

I should like a legend to show confidence intervals (shaded area) and line of best fit (red).

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

In `ggplot2`, the way to create a legend is to specify your aesthetics within `aes()`.  In this case, you have two separate aesthetics that you need to label: `color` should include one value that is labeled as "Line of Best Fit", and `fill` includes one value that is labeled as "Confidence Interval".

You don't have a column in your dataset to apply to these two aesthetics, but if you input a character string into `aes(color=..., fill=...)`, then the character string will be used as the label and the aesthetics will be created for you.  Observe how this works below when I use a made-up dataset that matches your own formatting.  Note in particular that `col="red"` is removed from the original code.  If it was not removed, it would overwrite the `color=` we placed inside `aes()`.

```
library(ggplot2)

set.seed(1234)
bats <- data.frame(
  Days=sample(1:30, 200, replace=TRUE),
  AI=rnorm(200, mean=50, sd=20)
)

p <- 
  ggplot(bats, aes(x=Days, y=AI))+geom_point(size=2, alpha=0.5) +
  xlab("Number of survey days") +
  ylab("Bat Activity Index")+
  stat_smooth(
    aes(color="Line of Best Fit", fill="Confidence Interval"),
    method = "lm",  formula = y~x, size = 1,
    level = 0.95, alpha=0.5
  )+
  theme_light() +
  ggtitle("Regression test between Bat Activity Index and number of survey days") 
p
```

[image]

Well, now we have the legends, but likely this does not look like intended.  The legend for color has a red line and a gray background, whereas the one for fill has a red background and a blue line!  This is because `ggplot2` is recognizing that `"Line of Best Fit"` and `"Confidence Interval"` are not the same string, so therefore creates different aesthetic values for both.  In any case, you will want to specify the correct `color` and `fill` value.

**Specifying Colors:** If you specify `fill=` and `color=` in `geom_smooth()`, it will overwrite the one we made in `aes()` and you will remove the legend.  Therefore, we will specify the value using `scale_color_manual()` and `scale_fill_manual()`.  We also do not want titles for the legends, so can remove it there too.

**Changing the Appearance of the Key Glyphs:** You also want to change the way the legends look.  For "Line of Best Fit", you want to remove the fill from that legend icon (called a "key glyph").  For "Confidence Interval", we want to remove the line and just show the gray box.  We can do all that using `guides()` and the `override.aes=` argument within `guide_legend()`.

**Position of Legends:** Finally, We want to move the legend to the bottom for a better overall look, which is accessed via the `legend.position=` element in `theme()`.  If you want to keep them on the right, you may want to modify the `theme()` elements for `legend.spacing` and `legend.margin` to get them a bit closer together.

Putting this all together we get the following:

```
p +
  scale_fill_manual(NULL, values = 'gray') +
  scale_color_manual(NULL, values = 'red') +
  guides(
    color=guide_legend(override.aes = list(fill=NA), order=1),
    fill=guide_legend(override.aes = list(color=NA), order=2)
  )+
  theme(legend.position = "bottom")
```

[image]